# syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting ')'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm trying to build a form in Ruby on Rails. The problem is, it keeps giving me an error syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting ')' when I start the table itself.

Here's the lines above the form:

```
<% @employee = SbmEmployee.search(@employee_id).first %> 
<!-- <h4><%= employee.first_name #+ " " + employee.middle_name + " " employee.last_name %></h4></br> -->
```

Here's the start of the form:

`<%= form_for :pr_add_ons_deductions, url: { action: "create" } do |f| %>`

This is where it's saying it is coming from, but I don't see anything wrong with it.

Here's the form itself which is where the '<' comes from.

```
    <table summary="Section from fields">
            <tr>
                <th>Resultant</th>
                <th><%= f.label(:type_id) %></th>
                <th><%= f.label(:description) %></th>
                <th><%= f.label(:amount) %></th>
                <th><%= f.label(:recurrence) %></th>
                <th><%= f.label(:end_date) %></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><select name="resultant" onchange="setResultant()"> <!--TODO-->
                    <option value="Add">Add On</option>
                    <option value="Deduct">Deduction</option>
                </td>
                <td><%= select(:pr_add_ons_deductions, :type_id, PrAddOnsDeductionsType.select_options) %></td>
                <td><%= f.text_area(:description, :size => '40x2')%></td>
                <td><%= f.text_field(:amount) %></td>
                <td><%= f.text_field(:recurrence) %></td>
                <td><%= date_select(:pr_add_ons_deductions, :end_date, :value => Time.now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")) %></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <div class="form-buttons">
            <%= submit_tag("Create Entry") %>
        </div>

<% end %>
```

Here's the contents of the controller:

```
def entry
        @employee_id = params[:id]
        @entry = PrAddOnsDeduction.new(:sbm_employee_id => params[:id])
    end

    def create
        @payroll = PrAddOnsDeduction.new(params)

        if @payroll.save
            flash[:notice] = "Entry Created Successfully."
            @payroll.save!
            redirect_to(:action => "entry")
        else 
            render("entry")
        end
    end
```

Besides this there is a params method that is private in the controller:

```
def params
        params.require(:pr_add_ons_deductions).permit(:type_id, :description, :amount, :recurrence, :end_date, :sbm_employee_id)
    end
```

Here's the model I use:

```
class SbmEmployee < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "sbm_employees"

    def self.search(id) 
        self.where("id = #{id}")
    end 
end
```

Comment: From what you've given, it all looks fine. Please, provide the whole template contents.

Comment: This is everything in the file.

Comment: @Padagomez Then where's your `<% end %>` tag for the `form_for`?

Comment: Apologies, there were a few lines at the bottom I missed when posting this.

Comment: Figured it out. I missed a + in the concatenation `<h4><%= employee.first_name #+ " " + employee.middle_name + " " employee.last_name %></h4>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run a bit of your ERB through `erubis -x` (note: Rails uses Erubis rather than plain ERB) to see what Ruby it is transpiled to, you'll see something like this:

```
_buf = ''; @employee = SbmEmployee.search(@employee_id).first  
 _buf << '<!-- <h4>'; _buf << ( employee.first_name #+ " " + employee.middle_name + " " employee.last_name ).to_s; _buf << '</h4></br> -->
'; _buf << ( form_for :pr_add_ons_deductions, url: { action: "create" } do |f| ).to_s; _buf << '
';
```

The second line is of interest here. Erubis has thrown your comment right into the generated code without caring or understanding its effect. That should tell you why you're seeing that particular error message.

There are some lessons here:

1. Ruby comments in ERB don't work quite like comments in Ruby code. ERB processors don't really understand Ruby, they just sling bits of text around in an attempt to generate valid Ruby code.
2. ERB doesn't understand HTML comments either, HTML comments are just more text to sling around.
3. Don't comment-out code to disable it, use revision control and delete the code instead.

If you delete Ruby comment inside the HTML comment:

```
<!-- <h4><%= employee.first_name %></h4></br> -->
```

then things should start working again. Or better, delete the whole HTML comment since it it just in the way.

Comment: To add to this, there were some errors in the commented code to boot. The declaration of the employee object was @employee, yet it is called as employee here. There's also a missing + in the concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your form tag in "`()`", and the URL param should look like this:

```
<%= form_for(:pr_add_ons_deductions, :url => {:controller => "your-controller-name", :action => "your-action-name"}) do |f| %>
```

Comment: :url => {:controller => "your-controller-name", :action => "your-action-name"}

Comment: @dane The `:controller` parameter is inferred when not specified.